# [npm]npm install will get stuck when it installs to the 53455th file

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I execute `npm install` under a vue project, and then it will get stuck when it installs 53455 files in node_modules.

No matter which package is being installed at this time, it stops as soon as the number of files reaches 53,455. This is the conclusion I have repeatedly observed.

I have been tossing for a whole day, and repeatedly clean the cache and reinstalling it, all useless.

My system is Windows 7 64 bit, nodejs is the latest version v14.15.3

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may fail due to some network error (or) to some admin rights. It's better to use administrator accessed cmd prompt.

then run **npm install**